# Pull down menu - Creating with <select> vs. <li>?

Tags: php, html

I've seen different sites use either `<select>` or `<li>` to create pull down menus on the website.  I was just wondering are there any benefits in using one over the other?  What are the differences?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<select>` is a "real" drop-down menu. People using `<li>` do so to allow for more freedom of customisation, as `<select>` can be very hard to apply CSS to.

Answer (score 1):

select dropdowns render differently in browsers than other inputs do, you will have a lot trouble with z-indexes, and styling across different browsers/OS's. You also can not predictably use tags within options and the various CSS opportunities that lists would provide.